# Binary Search using C# creating guessing game

Tags: c#, data-structures, binary-search, game-theory

I am beginner learning C# :

I need to use binary search to allow the computer to guess the user's "magic number" 5x. I know my `if` statement is flawed, but I am having a hard time translating binary search to code.

User picks number in their head and computer guesses user's number only allowing 5 chances. User selects 1 if the number the computer guesses is lower than the user's magic number, 2 if the number the computer guesses is higher than the user's magic number or 3 if the computer guesses correct.

Below is what I have so far.

```cs
using System;

namespace NumberGuessingGame
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int Low = 1;
            int High = 100;
            int DifferenceOfRange = High - Low;
            int Midpoint = DifferenceOfRange / 2;
            int MidValue = Low + Midpoint;
            int Count = 0;
            bool MagicNumber = true;

            Console.WriteLine("Pick a magic number between 1 to 100. Press enter to continue");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine("Is your magic number: {0}", MidValue);
            Console.WriteLine(" 1: No my magic number is lower \n 2: No my magic number is greater \n 3: That is my magic number! ");
            if (int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) == 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Computer Wins!");
                MagicNumber = false;
            }
            while (Low <= High && MagicNumber && Count <= 5)
            {                                   
                DifferenceOfRange = High - Low;
                Midpoint = DifferenceOfRange / 2;
                MidValue = Low + Midpoint;
              
                if (Low < High && int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) == 2)
                {
                    Low = MidValue + 1;
                    Console.WriteLine("Your number is {0}", MidValue);           
                }
                else if(Low > High && int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) == 1)
                {
                    High = MidValue - 1;
                    Console.WriteLine("Your number is {0}", MidValue);          
                }
                else if (Count >= 5)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer loses");
                }
                Count++;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to be asking a specific answerable question. "I am having a hard time translating binary search to code" is too broad/vague for us to help.

Comment: Every ReadLine() reads a *new* line

Comment: In C#, variables declared inside methods should start with a lowercase letter. PascalCase is used for `public` members declared underneath the word `class`

Answer (score 1):

You needed to readLine once, and store it in a variable to use for all of your if statements.

```
using System;


namespace NumberGuessingGame
{
  class Program
  {


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


      int Low = 1;
      int High = 100;
      int DifferenceOfRange = High - Low;
      int Midpoint = DifferenceOfRange / 2;
      int MidValue = Low + Midpoint;
      int Count = 1;
      bool MagicNumber = true;

      Console.WriteLine("Pick a magic number between 1 to 100. Press enter to continue");
      Console.ReadKey();
      while (Low <= High && MagicNumber)
      {
        DifferenceOfRange = High - Low;
        Midpoint = DifferenceOfRange / 2;
        MidValue = Low + Midpoint;

        Console.WriteLine("Is your magic number: {0}", MidValue);
        Console.WriteLine(" 1: No my magic number is lower \n 2: No my magic number is greater \n 3: That is my magic number! ");
          int userChoice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (userChoice == 3)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Computer Wins!");
          MagicNumber = false;
        }

        if (Low < High && userChoice == 2)
        {
          Low = MidValue + 1;
          //Console.WriteLine("Your number is {0}", MidValue);
        }
        else if (Low < High && userChoice == 1)
        {
          High = MidValue - 1;
          //Console.WriteLine("Your number is {0}", MidValue);
        }
        if (Count >= 5)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Computer loses");
          MagicNumber = false;
        }
        Count++;
      }      
    }

  }

}
```